# How to re-use Windows (.dll) or Linux (.so) inside VS2015 Xamarin.Forms (PCL) targeting Android platform

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, wrapper

The error appears when I try to execute the project in actual device (Samsung Galaxy Tab A):

> Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: FWLIB32.dll

---

**Scenario**

>>*Linux*<<

1. libfwlib32.so.1.0.1 is provided by vendor (for Linux arm and x86, cannot edit)
2. fwlib32.h is provided by vendor (can edit or just call it)

>>*Windows*<<

1. Fwlib32.dll is provided by vendor (for Windows, cannot edit)
2. Fwlib32.cs is provided by vendor (DLL import/marshalling for the dll, can edit)

Fwlib32.cs example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Focas1
{
        /* allocate library handle 3 */
        [DllImport("FWLIB32.dll", EntryPoint = "cnc_allclibhndl3")]
        public static extern short cnc_allclibhndl3([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] Object ip,
            ushort port, int timeout, out ushort FlibHndl);
}
```

---

**Background**

I have made a Xamarin Forms project on VS2015 (Cross-Platform -> Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable). The target platform is Android. So I only have 2 projects: MyProject (Portable) and MyProject.Droid.

I have a vendor supplied DLL (I guess it is written with C/C++/BASIC), Fwlib32.dll  and a wrapper is provided, Fwlib32.cs. I added both the dll and cs file inside MyProject (Portable) project.

From the MyProjectPage.xaml.cs, I called one of the function, and nothing else, under the constructor.

```
public MyProjectPage()
{
    //function call to fwlib32.dll with wrapper from fwlib32.cs
    ushort h;
    ushort p = (ushort)int.Parse("8196", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);

    int ret = Focas1.cnc_allclibhndl3("192.168.0.1", p, 5, out h); //<-error here
}
```

This MyProjectPage is called by the App.cs.

```
public App()
{
    MainPage = new MyProjectPage();
}
```

The function call gets identified (no red line underneath) and the project compiles successfully.

---

**Issue**

When try to run on the device, the error message as shown above is pop-up on the VS2015, the execution stopped at the function call line. A snipplet of the debug message is as following.

> 06-09 11:50:35.826 D/Mono    (12497): DllImport error loading library
>   'libFWLIB32.dll': 'dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/MyProject.Droid-1/lib/arm/libFWLIB32.dll" not found'. 06-09
>   11:50:35.836 D/Mono    (12497): DllImport error loading library
>   'libFWLIB32.dll.so': 'dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/MyProject.Droid-1/lib/arm/libaot-libFWLIB32.dll.so" not
>   found'. 06-09 11:50:35.836 D/Mono    (12497): DllImport error loading
>   library 'libFWLIB32.dll': 'dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/MyProject.Droid-1/lib/arm/libFWLIB32.dll" not found'. 06-09
>   11:50:35.836 W/Mono    (12497): DllImport unable to load library
>   'dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/MyProject.Droid-1/lib/arm/libFWLIB32.dll" not found'.

---

**What has been done**

I try to add the DLL to the reference but it is not able to do so. Error message is

> A reference to 'C:...\Projects\MyProject\FWLIB32\Fwlib32.dll' could
>   not be added. The method or operation is not implemented.

*[Update as suggested by SushiHangover, 9 Jun]*

I created a Fwlib32.Android which is Android Class Library project in VS2015. Then added in the fwlib32.cs and Fwlib32.dll. From the dll Properties, changed the Build Action to AndroidNativeLibrary, and Copy always.

Then under MyProject.Droid, I added the reference to the newly created DLL. Compile and System.DllNotFoundException still occur.

*[Working with Android Studio.......]*

... no data ...

---

**Help**

Do you have any idea how should I approach this problem to get the function call working? 
Specifically the following:

(a) How to write the code to make use the vendor supplied .dll or .so and recompile it with Android Studio to make Android version .so?

(b) How to import and use the Android version .so in Xamarin?

Thank you.
Lee

Comment: On Android you will need to supply an Android-based native library (not a Window's native DLL) that supports each of the ABIs that you planned to deploy to:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

Comment: I am not able to ask vendor to supply a Android-based native library.